# Remove shortcut key to increase volume slider

Tags: 10.04, sound, shortcut-keys

I keep making this mistake:
Adjust the volume using the icon on the task bar, then without clicking somewhere else, try to change desktops (Ctrl+Alt+Right), get 100% volume blaring in my headphones.

Does anyone know how to remove the keyboard shortcut for this? It's not under System>Preferences>Keyboard shortcuts

I'm surprised I can't find anyone else complaining about this, my work mate also has the same problem.

Comment: With the slider selected, the arrow keys increase and decrease the volume by small steps, Ctrl+Left jumps to 0% and Ctrl+Right jumps to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a scroll wheel on your mouse, then you don't have to open the volume control. You can just hold the pointer over the volume icon and scroll up and down. At least it is that way now. I'm not entirely sure if that was implemented yet in 10.04, but it is worth a try. Perhaps that is easier to get used to than it is to close the sound menu.

(The problem itself if pretty much unfixable since the slider is supposed to have focus when you use it so that you can use the keyboard)